# WordPress Filter for changing author list in edit post Authors box

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, wordpress-hook

I want to change the list of users in the Author select dropdown on the edit post page for a custom post type. Is there a filter hook I can use for this? I haven't been able to find any information on a filter hook that does what I want.

The hook should (in theory) let me return a user array and those will be the users that populate the select box at the bottom. The reason I want to do this is so I can conditionally filter out users by their role for different post types. As an admin (or other admins) I don't want to have to check if user has certain role before making them the author.

Example of code:

```
add_filter('example_filter', 'my_custom_function');
function my_custom_function ( $users ){

    // Get users with role 'my_role' for post type 'my_post_type'
    if( 'my_post_type' == get_post_type() ){
        $users = get_users( ['role' => 'my_role'] );
    }

    // Get users with role 'other_role' for post type 'other_post_type'
    if( 'other_post_type' == get_post_type() ){
        $users = get_users( ['role' => 'other_role'] );
    }

    return $users;
}
```

Comment: can we see your code ?

Comment: Not sure why this question got downvoted... Updated the question with some more clarification and details along with some sample code. I don't have any code in my theme right now though because I don't have a filter to hook into.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use hook 'wp_dropdown_users_args'.

Add below code snippet in your theme's functions.php file.

```
add_filter( 'wp_dropdown_users_args', 'change_user_dropdown', 10, 2 );

function change_user_dropdown( $query_args, $r ){
    // get screen object
    $screen = get_current_screen();

    // list users whose role is e.g. 'Editor' for 'post' post type
    if( $screen->post_type == 'post' ):
        $query_args['role'] = array('Editor');

        // unset default role 
        unset( $query_args['who'] );
    endif;

    // list users whose role is e.g. 'Administrator' for 'page' post type
    if( $screen->post_type == 'page' ):
        $query_args['role'] = array('Administrator');

        // unset default role 
        unset( $query_args['who'] );
    endif;

    return $query_args;
}
```

Let me know if this works for you or not.

Comment: Thank you!! It's been a while but that's the exact thing I was looking for!

Comment: thanks, I have added `['role_in']` argument for the multiple user roles.

Comment: This function works well; I combined it with some of the argument suggestions from the Codex comments: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_dropdown_users_args/#comment-4087 

However, if the post editor is using Gutenberg, this filter doesn't fire. You'll need to work with the `rest_user_query` filter instead (or in addition; they receive and return the same arguments, so I'm using one function for both filters). Note that this filter is used for a lot more than the Author dropdown, so use it thoughtfully (and conditionally), though.

Comment: According to Sarah Lewis: Note that if you’re trying to filter the “Author” dropdown on the post editor screen, and the post editor is using Gutenberg, this filter doesn’t fire. You’ll need to work with the rest_user_query filter instead. (But also note that this filter is used for a lot more than the Author dropdown, so use it thoughtfully.)
(https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_dropdown_users_args/#comment-6209)